# How to find an element by the for attribute or class names?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a button and I have this info. There is no id, and I only have the following code:

[image]

How could I make a `findElement` using the highlighted info?

I tried with

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("icon f_checkbox inlblk vtop")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the driver that those are classes

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='icon f_checkbox inlblk vtop']")).click();
```

Or simplified

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon.f_checkbox.inlblk.vtop")).click();
```

If you want to use the `for` attribute

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[for='renderCheckbox1-1']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use CSS selectors, you need to follow some rules like [Here](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors).

For Class in CSS it’s just `“.”` so instead of

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("icon f_checkbox inlblk vtop").click();
```

try (given this is unique class otherwise you probably will need to share bigger part of HTML) below (as Guy suggested).

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon.f_checkbox.inlblk.vtop").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to send multiple *classnames* using `findElement()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) and only the *classNames* as follows:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".icon.f_checkbox.inlblk.vtop")
  ```
- Using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) along with the *tagName* and the *classnames* as follows:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label.icon.f_checkbox.inlblk.vtop")
  ```
- Using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='icon f_checkbox inlblk vtop']")
  ```

---

However, as per the HTML you have shared, you may need to club up some of the other attributes to locate the element uniquely with in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- Using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) along with the *tagName* and the *classnames* as follows:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label.icon.f_checkbox.inlblk.vtop[for='renderCheckbox1-1']")
  ```
- Using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='icon f_checkbox inlblk vtop' and @for='renderCheckbox1-1']")
  ```